# Common Lisp best practices to use type declarations for optimization

Tags: optimization, common-lisp, compiler-optimization

I have a Common Lisp function that merges two ordered lists of symbols, without duplicates (two ordered sets):

```
(defun my-merge (x y)
  "merge two lists of symbols *already sorted and without duplicates*
   (and return the resulting list sorted and without duplicates)"
  (let* ((first (cons nil nil))
         (last first))
    (loop while (and x y)
       for cx = (car x)
       for cy = (car y)
       if (string= cx cy)
       do (setf x (cdr x))
       else if (string< cx cy)
       do (rplacd last (cons cx nil))
       and do (setf last (cdr last) 
                    x (cdr x))
       else do (rplacd last (cons cy nil))
       and do (setf last (cdr last) 
                    y (cdr y)))
    (rplacd last (or x y))
    (cdr first)))
```

Since I have found only scarce information about the use of type declarations in practical cases in order to compile efficiently the code, I am unsure if it is sufficient to declare the variables, for instance in this way:

```
(defun my-merge (x y)
  "merge two list of symbols *already sorted and without duplicates*"
  (declare (list x y))
  (let* ((first (cons nil nil))
         (last first))
    (declare (cons first last))
    (loop while (and x y)
       for cx symbol = (car x)
       for cy symbol = (car y)
       ...
```

or, as I suppose, if it is necessary also to add the `the` specifier to my code? But then, *where* and in *which cases* should I add it?

*There is some rule that one can follow?*

*Should I also declare the type of my functions, again for the optimization purposes?*

Comment: Optimization, use of type declarations for optimizations and type inference is fully implementation specific. You'll find everything in implementations: from zero optimization based on type declarations, use of type declarations and even *type inference* (which means fewer type declarations are necessary). Generally: declare types and optimize, then look at the generated assembler and/or measure times. If you use SBCL, CMUCL or LispWorks, the compiler will (or can be configured to) tell you where it can't optimize and why. Then one would add the necessary declarations.

Comment: It's always fun to roll your own solutions, but do note that one of the best options might just be to use the standard [**merge**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_merge.htm) function. It can produce arbitrary sequence types, takes arbitrary predicates, etc., and the implementations may have optimized it already (it might be worthwhile looking at their source).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, this was my first choice, but then I tested the merge function both of SBCL and of CCL, which are the implementation that I currently use, and *both* had a performance which is significantly worst that this function on large lists (don't remember the exact numbers). I don't know the reason, either, or maybe I did something wrong in performing the test.

Comment: Rainer's reply is accurate.  This is a frustrating aspect of the language's evolution since it was originally blocked out.

Comment: @renzo, we'll, that's a good reason to looking into rolling your own then! Too often, optimization questions haven't even considered the standard library functions. Since Co's merge sports different types of input and output, it might well be less efficient than a specialized version. About testing, I'd say to be sure to try turning safety down,not *just* adding type declarations. Types tell the compiler one more thing it can check,safety tells it that it doesn't have to.

Comment: @Renzo, did you also try `union`, since you don't want duplicates?

Comment: @RainerJoswig, you are certainly right, but even the implementation documentations are really scarce in details about this topic. For instance, I found no trace in [CCL](http://ccl.clozure.com/docs/ccl.html) documentation, and some more on [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Efficiency), but still unsatisfactory.

Comment: @jkiiski, I forget to mention (and to write in the documentation of the function!) that I need the result list sorted (while union do not guarantee such property).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, thanks. Also, after debugging, I turned on the compiler options to favor speed over security and debugging.

Comment: I suppose you have already considered other data structures for your problem? You mentioned that the lists are large, and lists usually aren't optimal for large amounts of data. Without knowing what you're doing it's hard to say, but arrays with pre-allocated space might be faster.

Comment: @Renzo Do you have any code that you're using for *testing* your merge?  Some sample inputs could help a bit

Comment: @jkiiski, the function that I used in my question is an example that I had in hand to ask about what was my focus: how to use type declaration to speed up the code. I've seen many examples, but what escapes to me is exactly when put the `the` type declaration and when not. Of course my example is not particularly interesting, and other data structures could be much more efficient (my program is about functional dependencies, and I use lists for set of attributes).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor here is the (naive) test (I've changed the function for testing integers and not symbols): `(time (progn (my-merge (loop for i from 0 to 1000000 collect i) (loop for i from 0 to 1000000 collect (+ 500 i))) "Done!"))` vs. `(time (progn (merge 'list (copy-list (loop for i from 0 to 1000000 collect i)) (copy-list (loop for i from 0 to 1000000 collect (+ 500 i)) #'=)) "Done!"))` . Note the copy-list, which is needed since merge is destructive (and `my-merge` must create a new list and allocates memory as well). As said in a comment, my focus is more about optimization through types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Style**

Since you don't actually use the extended `LOOP` features in any useful way and the `LOOP` syntax isn't that great for your example, I would propose to write it with the primitive `LOOP`. See how `COND` makes it more readable for a Lisp programmer:

```
(defun my-merge (x y &aux (first (list nil)) (last first) cx cy)
  (macrolet ((cdr! (v)
               `(setf ,v (cdr ,v))))
    (loop (unless (and x y)
            (return))
          (setf cx (car x) cy (car y))
          (cond ((string= cx cy)
                 (cdr! x))
                ((string< cx cy)
                 (rplacd last (list cx))
                 (cdr! last)
                 (cdr! x))
                (t
                 (rplacd last (list cy))
                 (cdr! last)
                 (cdr! y))))
    (rplacd last (or x y))
    (cdr first)))
```

**Compiling**

Given the level of sophistication of a compiler:

- fully stupid = compiler ignores all declarations -> declarations don't help
- mostly stupid = compiler needs declarations everywhere, but optimizes -> you need to write a lot of declarations

example:

```
(let ((a 1) (b 2))
  (declare (integer a b))
  (let ((c (the integer (* (the integer (+ a b))
                           (the integer (- a b))))))
     (declare (integer c))
     (the integer (* c c))))
```

Note that it might not enough to know what the argument types are, it might be necessary to declare the type of results. Thus the use of `the`.  `DISASSEMBLE` and the profiler are your friends.

- basic = compiler needs type declarations, optimizes, but also can infer some types. Types for the standard language is known.

Even better compilers complain about type errors, can propagate types across functions and can complain when certain optimizations are not possible.

**Sequence functions**

Note that *sequence* functions are a particular tough case. *Sequences* have as subtypes *lists* and *vectors* (including strings).

Let's say a sequence function is:

```
(foo result-type sequence-1 sequence-2 fn)
```

- if the sequences are of the same type, one might want to have an optimized code versions for lists and another one for vectors.
- if the sequences are of different types, it might be useful to convert one sequences to a different type. Maybe not.
- the result type also has influence, depending on result types, different algorithms may be possible/necessary

So the degree of freedom is quite high. The compiler might contribute to fast code. But also the implementation of the particular sequence function might be able to do some optimization at runtime.

Then `fn` is a function which takes elements and produces new elements. It might be helpful to know its type signature - or not.

I can't really say which current Common Lisp has a sophisticated implementation of the sequence functions. Though I remember that the Symbolics Common Lisp implementations put some effort into it.

**Documentation and papers**

Often what the compiler can optimize and how is not well documented, if at all. There are some papers about this topic, but often they are old and/or outdated.

- The *Python* compiler of CMUCL: [The Compiler](https://common-lisp.net/project/cmucl/doc/cmu-user/compiler.html).
- The *Python* compiler of CMUCL: [Advanced Compiler Use](https://common-lisp.net/project/cmucl/doc/cmu-user/compiler-hint.html).
- [The Python compiler for CMU Common Lisp](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ram/pub/lfp.ps) (Postscript)
- [SBCL Compiler](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Compiler)
- Allegro CL: [Compiling](http://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/compiling.htm)
- LispWorks: [Optimizing your code](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/LW/html/lw-63.htm#pgfId-887598)
- [Performance beyond expectations](http://www.ai.sri.com/~quam/Public/papers/ILC2005/Lisp-performance.pdf)
- [How to make Lisp code go faster than C](http://www.iaeng.org/IJCS/issues_v32/issue_4/IJCS_32_4_19.pdf)
- [An evaluation of major Lisp compilers](http://cl-www.msi.co.jp/solutions/knowledge/lisp-world/tutorial/compiler-eval-e.pdf)

Comment: Really great answer, thank you very much for your code, as well as for the explanations and all the links! Food for the mind.